# What is the connection between RFB protocol and VNC protocol

Tags: vnc, rfb-protocol

So I have read about RFB protocol and VNC protocol, But I Don't understands the connection between the two.

I'm reading this :   http://www.realvnc.com/docs/rfbproto.pdf
And all I see is explaination about RFB protocol, but I don't understand where vnc connect to it.

VNC is like a name for program that send and recieve frame-buffer? and RFB is the actuall protocol that does that?

thanks

Answer (score 13):

You could consider Virtual Network Computing to be a concept that simply allows one computer to delegate it's GUI display to another machine for the sake of convenience.  VNC is also the name of a product and a trademark of RealVNC Ltd in the UK.  People generally use the term "VNC" informally to denote that generic category of software.

If you wanted to create your own system that allows virtual computing over a network then you might choose to use the existing RFB protocol to do so since it is likely that doing so will make your product easier to deploy given that many remote clients already exist.  Equally you might choose to ignore RFB altogether and invent your own replacement protocol.

To put it another way, if you create a system that **uses** the RFB then you have technically made a VNC system in an informal sense.  RFB is designed specifically for VNC systems but could be used to extend the capabilities of existing products.

A full VNC system consists of two parts, a client and a server.  RFB is the protocol that governs the format used for passing data between the two.

There are many clients available already on the web, many of them free.  If you create your own VNC server and adhere to the RFB specification then these pre-existing clients will be compatible with your system.

For further information...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing

Comment: This is such a great explanation and summery! I believe, to understand this I had to read 15 pages on 10 different websites. Thank you very much mate, you made my day!

Comment: @YasinNazlıcan, you're very welcome :)  Good luck with your project.